# Facebook Auth and CSRF mechanism

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, csrf

I am currently building a website using facebook authentication. I am running locally and keep getting CSRF errors. I am trying to understand their CSRF protection mechanism:

```
 $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 $_SESSION['state']= $_REQUEST['state'];//GETS SITE WORKING BUT UNSAFE!!!///

 if(empty($code)) {
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection

 $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
 }

 if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
```

What happens is that it seems my $_REQUEST['state'] is set but my $_SESSION['state'] is not. Hence to get it working i have the line which sets both equal. My $code variable never seems to be empty hence a new $_SESSION['state' variable is never set.

Firstly what is the role of $_REQUEST['code'] and where does this/is this variable come from/set?

Any ideas how to fix this with my unsafe line of code?

p.s I know I should use the FB sdk, but am learning web design/security so this is a good exercise to learn how it works!!

Many Thanks Sam

---

To anybody who is interested, I have worked out how it works, but  still haven't fixed my problem...Anyway

The CSFR protection system works by saving a State 'ID' on the server-side in the $_SESSION['state'], the same ID is saved also inside the $_REQUEST['state'] , so on the client side. This therefore means if a CSRF attack occurs, the state value of the CSRF attack (client side) won't match that of $_SESSION['state'] hence the code does not proceed and the attack is prevented.

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Your description is essentially correct, the state value that is in the url when redirected back to your site ($_REQUEST['state']) should match the state value that was assigned when first redirecting to Facebook (stored in $_SESSION['state']). If they do not match, some "manipulation" has occurred and you should not proceed.

But you also said that $_SESSION['state'] was not being set because $code is never empty. If that is the case, then how is the redirect to Facebook ever occuring?

It seems more likely that session values are not being retained in general. Is this the only place in your site that you use sessions?

Note that you don't have to use a session if that is problematic. If you have a database set up, you can use that just as easily. Or you can avoid local storage completely, as long as you conceive a way to be reasonably sure that the state value you receive was actually created by your code as part of the intended sequence. For example, you might set the state value to the current timestamp concatenated with an md5 of the timestamp plus a secret string. When the state value comes back, first check the timestamp portion to ensure it was created within the last minute or two, and then check the md5 to make sure it wasn't created by someone else. That way you have a simple token that can't be guessed in advance and can't be re-used, the two basic requirements for CSRF prevention.

Comment: Yes that is right, I realised that my $_SESSIONs were not working properly went integrating my other user pages. It seems my cookies were not working properly, but I have fixed this and the problem still persists. I'm just putting this down to the awkwardness of running it on a local server!

Comment: If sessions are working otherwise but giving you trouble here, it may not be worth spending too much time tinkering with them for this one purpose. I've edited my answer a bit with some other options you might consider.